# Electron js - Como guardar una imagen desde electron js a una carpeta dentro del proyecto?

Tags: nodejs, electron

estoy intentando guardar imágenes de productos a una carpeta que hice dentro de mi proyecto pero no me esta funcionando, apenas soy nuevo y no estoy entiendo mucho a la documentacion, les dejo lo que tengo

En mi proyecto en la carpeta raiz tengo el Main.js. de ahi tengo otra carpeta que se llama UI donde tengo todo el renderizado y en esa misma carpeta UI hice una carpeta llamada imagenes, es ahi donde quiero cargar las imagenes de los productos que voy agregando a la base de datos.

Mi codigo:

```
var fs = require('fs');
    const {dialog} = require('electron').remote
    const path = require('path');

save.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    dialog.showSaveDialog({
        title: 'Select the File Path to save',
        defaultPath: path.join(__dirname, './imagenes/'),
        buttonLabel: 'Save',
        // Restricting the user to only Text Files. 
        filters: [{
            name: 'Imagenes',
            extensions: ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
        }, ],
        properties: []
    }).then(file => {
        if (!file.canceled) {
            fs.writeFile(file.filePath.toString(),
                'This is a Sample File',
                function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Saved!');
                });
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

La ventana para seleccionar imágenes me funciona bien, pero cuando selecciono la imagen me parece una mensaje "quieres remplazar la imagen" y cuando le doy si o no, y doy clic en guardar la imagen que seleccione no se guarda. Me podrian orientar en que estoy fallando? Gracias compañeros